# Sqlite: create trigger programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite

When my App gets installed for the first time, I create a database programmatically. Works fine so far. But when I want to add a trigger, I get an exception saying "syntax error near IF". The problem is, that I can not span the String over multiple lines in source code. So what can I do instead?

```
private void createTriggers(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    final String triggerLocationArchived = "CREATE TRIGGER location_archived AFTER UPDATE ON location FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.deleted <> OLD.deleted THEN UPDATE sector set sector.deleted = NEW.deleted WHERE sector.location = NEW._id; END IF; END;";

    database.execSQL(triggerLocationArchived);
}
```

There are two tables: location and sector. Each has an INTEGER flag indicating if the row has been archived. So I want all children (sectors within a location) to be archived as well if the parent (the location) is archived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER location_archived 
 AFTER UPDATE ON location 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 WHEN NEW.deleted <> OLD.deleted 
 BEGIN 
    UPDATE sector 
    set deleted = NEW.deleted 
    WHERE location = NEW._id; 
 END
```

Your code will look like this:

```
private void createTriggers(SQLiteDatabase database) {

     final String triggerLocationArchived = "CREATE TRIGGER location_archived AFTER UPDATE ON [location] FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.deleted <> OLD.deleted BEGIN UPDATE sector set deleted = NEW.deleted WHERE location = NEW._id; END";

     database.execSQL(triggerLocationArchived);
}
```

Comment: You can not define a String in multiple lines within Java source Code

Comment: Formatting is for display only. Your command is wrong. The exception,  "syntax error near IF", happened because you can't use "if", look again, I changed the "if" to "when". Remove formatting and put in your code. It'll work.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Tried it now but does not work either. Now it says error "near "WHEN": syntax error"

Comment: It should work. If you change only the "`if`" to "`when`" in your code, this won't work . I removed the "`begin`" before "`for each row`" and I changed the "`then`" after "`for each row`" to "`begin`" ,too. Copy my command and paste in your code.

Comment: Did not work :( Says syntax error near "." I'm using this line (added another column to the UPDATE): CREATE TRIGGER location_archived AFTER UPDATE ON location FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.deleted <> OLD.deleted BEGIN UPDATE sector set sector.deleted = NEW.deleted, sector.sync = 1 WHERE sector.location = NEW._id; END;END;

Comment: I think that alias is not acepted in triggers update command. I was executing this command in SQLiteExpert and I changed your tables names to my tables names and I tested, and it work, because I removed the table alias. So I'll edit my answer, you need to remove all table alias `sector.`.